# OpenCV: selectROI returning zero tuple

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to crop the region of Interest using `selectROI`. But in my code `selectROI` is always  returning (0, 0, 0, 0) as the tuple. I tried this with different images, but the issue still remains there. Can someone help me in this?

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    img = cv2.imread('diff-overlay.jpg')
    r = cv2.selectROI("Image", img, False, False)
    imCrop = img[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]
    cv2.imshow("Image", imCrop)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are expected to crop the region on the image displayed using your mouse. After you have selected the region of interest , hit the `Enter` key and it will return the cropped image. Now when you check the value of `r` it returns a tuple of the top-left and bottom-right coordinates of the cropped image.

**Code:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Read image
    im = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Desktop/Bengal_cat.png")

    # Select ROI
    r = cv2.selectROI(im, False, False)

    # Crop image
    imCrop = im[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]

    # Display cropped image
    cv2.imshow("Image", imCrop)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Illustration:**

Assume I have the following image:

[image]

Now when the code executes `r = cv2.selectROI(im, False, False)`
, the image appears where you can crop using the mouse:

[image]

Upon hitting the 'Enter' key (or any other key), the cropped image is displayed:

[image]

That's all that there is to it !!

- Variable `r` returns a tuple, which in this case is : `(31, 65, 125, 120)`

where,

```
(31, 65, 125, 120)
 ^   ^    ^    ^
 |   |    |    |
 x1  y1   |    y2 = 120 + 65
          x2 = 125 + 31
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Actually I was pressing the' C' key.(After which the line was getting executed with (0,0,0,0) as the value of r). I guess only the enter key works.

Comment: Thanks. One thing I noted is that the third element in the tuple is the width and the last argument is the length of the rectangle. That is why we are writing `r[1]+r[3]` in the code. It is the Y-axis distance for the bottom of rectangle.

Comment: @SubhamKumar Sorry for the negligence. I have edited the answer with your finding.

Answer (score 0):

image top right corner is origin

`X` increase downwards

`Y` increase from left to right

top left corner is `x1,y1`
bottom left corner is `x2,y2`

so image[y1:y2,x1:x2] should give you the selected area of interest

[Image ROI](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html)